# Enumeration is considered as Iterator by JVM

Tags: java, iterator, java-7, enumeration

I wonder why **java.util.Enumeration** is considered as j**ava.util.Iterator** by JVM? They haven't any inheritance relationship.

```
public interface Enumeration<E> {
....
}

public interface Iterator<E> {
...
}

Hashtable<String, Object> hashTable = new Hashtable<>();
hashTable.put("key1", 1);
hashTable.put("key2", 2);
hashTable.put("key3", 3);
Enumeration<Object> enumeration = hashTable.elements();
System.out.println(enumeration instanceof Enumeration);
System.out.println(enumeration instanceof Iterator);// why true here?
```

Comment: If you want to investigate type relationships, use `X.class.isAssignableFrom( Y.class )`. It isn't tainted by an *object's* fortuities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `instanceof` operator compares an object to a specified **type**.

Since the returned `Enumarator` implemented the type  `Iterator`, the condition became  `true`.

```
 private class Enumerator<T> implements Enumeration<T>, Iterator<T>
```

Here is the source code of [`HashTable's Enumerator<T>`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#Hashtable.Enumerator) definition.

Comment: The key piece of the puzzle is that `instanceof` checks the actual type of the object and not the declared type of the variable. This is in fact the purpose of `instanceof`, otherwise it would be fairly useless :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterator and Enumeration are interfaces.  They are declaration and cannot be instantiated.  So whatever elements() returns it will be an instantiation implementing the Enumeration interface.

If you look into the Hashtable code and you'll end up with an instance returned of type java.util.Hashtable.Enumerator implements Enumeration, Iterator

So that's why :)

Answer (score 0):

`hashTable.elements()` return a `java.util.Hashtable.Enumerator` object, and this class implements both `java.util.Enumeration`, `java.util.Iterator`